# Java8 - filter Parent list based on the condition in Child list using Streams & lambda

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I would like to filter the parent list based on the condition in the sublist. Here parent list is List and sublist is List. I would like to get the list of students whose first subject's marks are more than or equals to 70.

```
        // College Class which has list of students.           
        public class College {
            private long collegeId;
            private List<Student> students;
         }

        // Student class which has list of subjects.
        public class Student {
            private long studentId;
            private List<Subject> subjects;
        }

        // Subject class.
        public class Subject {
            private long subjectId;
            private String subjectName;
            private long marks;
        }
```

now I would like to get all the list of students whose first subject's marks are >70.

I am trying something like below; but getting the "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27745".

```
        List<Student> distinctionStudents = college.getStudents().stream().filter(s -> s.getSubjects().get(0).getMarks()>=70).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not sure how to get this done.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It does not look like this code should produce this expection. There's something else. Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
    List<Student> list = students.stream()
            .filter(student -> !student.getSubjects().isEmpty())
            .filter(student ->
                    student.getSubjects().stream().findFirst().get().getMarks() >= 70)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For example, for below list of students:

```
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    students.add(new Student(1, new ArrayList<>()));
    students.add(new Student(1, Arrays.asList(
            new Subject(1, "A", 67),
            new Subject(2, "B", 76))));
    students.add(new Student(2, Arrays.asList(
            new Subject(1, "A", 99),
            new Subject(3, "C", 77))));
```

the output would be (of course for provided proper methods such `toString`):

```
list = [Student{studentId=2, subjects=[Subject{subjectId=1, subjectName='A', marks=99}, Subject{subjectId=3, subjectName='C', marks=77}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. But I am still getting the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27745. When I comment out the two filters; there is no exception; but when I uncomment any one of the .filter then I am getting the below exception.         SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-serlvet] in web application [/FlightAvailabilityPredictor] threw load() exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27745

Comment: I have tried that code as well. Same result. Not sure if this is related to code; I am using the jersey-client 1.8 version; does it related to the Jersey libraries?

Comment: @Hruday This question abstracts from jersey. Clearly you asked about pure list, no mentioned about jersey :)

Comment: My mistake; I was not aware that it could be because of jersey

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer; I was using the Jersey 1.8 library; and have moved to the below and it has worked.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you every one for previous time. It helped me to improve my code.

Comment: It is a pity you did not mentioned clearer about your problem. At least, please describe your problem and how you solve in details (for other people) :)